# React Hooks - Single instance of state

Tags: javascript, react.js

I was writing a little coding kata, and wanted to have a hook which managed a list of names. The hook should allow adding a name to the list, and also make the list available to the component.

I didn't want to bring in a state management library, or complicate the code with having to `useDispatch` or anything like that. I also didn't want to bring in a package that explicitly enables a `useSharedState` or `useGlobal` thing. Here's what I came up with.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

let list: string[] = []; // Force a single instance of a list, even if Hook is used in multiple places

const useNameList = () => {
    const [, _setList] = useState<string[]>(list);
    const [lastSelectedItem, setLastSelectedItem] = useState<string | null>(null);

    return {
        add: (name: string) => {
            list = [...list, name];
            // Components are delayed on detecting state updates if you don't explicitly update the hook state too...
            _setList(list);
        },
        names: list
    }
};

export default useNameList;
```

By setting the `list` up outside the hook, it forces there to be one instance. However, I still need to `setList` within a `useState`; without doing that, there was some buggy stuff happening across different components.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What exactly do you think your current code is lacking? And is this code working as intended or not?